# Create Outlook Email in C# with anchor tag in body that has a target

Tags: c#, html, email, outlook, smtp

My team and I have a very specific and frustrating issue.  We have an MVC4 web application that many people utilized within a company (no external exposure).  Some of our processes generate emails to other employees with links back to the application.

For example, there may be some activity that one employee sees and wants to attend.  They can can an email to the other employee saying they would like to attend.

In these emails, we put an anchor tag in with the link back to our application and some query string stuff to help direct it to the right page.

All of that works wonderfully.  Now, the problem is, we want the link (from the email) to load in an existing window with the application, if it exists.  Normally, I believe, this would be done with setting the target attribute in the anchor tag, but that doesn't work, it just opens in a new tab.

This is what the anchor tag source from the email looks like (i've changed some text so that it hides company related info):

```
Please <a target="appMain" href='http://domain/app/controller.aspx/view?
keyname=querystringparam1&params={"prop1":val,"prop2":va;}'>
click here</a> to approve and go to app
```

this is our smtp function to send the mail:

```
public void SendMail(EmailContent emailContent, string mailConfigurationPath)
   {
       var toRecipients = string.Join(",", emailContent.ToList);

       var mailMessage = new MailMessage(emailContent.From, toRecipients)
       {
           IsBodyHtml = emailContent.IsBodyHtml,
           Body = emailContent.Body,
           Subject = emailContent.Subject
       };

       var smtpClient = new SmtpClient
       {
           DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory,
           PickupDirectoryLocation = mailConfigurationPath
       };

       smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
   }
```

Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible? It seems pretty straight forward, maybe I'm just going about it the wrong way.  Would love some help or even some "crazy" ideas.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You might be able to create a landing page that `window.open`s a named window, but it would probably have to be used when users login organically too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, because it creates a vulnerability in the email program itself...

http://thenextweb.com/insider/2013/01/07/yahoo-mail-users-hit-by-widespread-hacking-xss-exploit-seemingly-to-blame/

Also, it goes against all the normal user interface guidelines for email programs. Users don't expect an email to transform into an app. They are very familiar with clicking on links in emails though, so you wouldn't want that action to do something weird.

Comment: So the 'target' attribute in email anchor tags are unusable?

Comment: It isn't that. It's that most email programs don't allow access of outside resources, and won't be able to make a request to your web server to retrieve additional content. You can get around that with iframes and javascript, but you'll eventually hit a security wall.